# Address search for Lightning Scheduler is not working in Community

Tags: community, lightning-experience, lightning-community, community-builder, lightning-scheduler

I'm creating a lightning scheduler for the Guest user.

I have a standard lightning Scheduler for Guest User flow on my public Community page. 
But the Service Territory search page is not working. Ideally, it should show all the addresses for whatever I enter in the field.

When I run the same flow inside the salesforce it shows all the addresses.

I may be missing some settings, but not sure what.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look on the sharing settings if Service appointments / work types and work type group objects are read only as minimum.

Also, you can check:  CSP Trusted Site | if it is configured the following URL test.location.force.com

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try adding test-location.force.com to CSP and CORS. Also, in Community> Security settings> trusted Site for Scripts. If it didn't work, try disabling "Enable Browser Cross Site Scripting Protection" in sites corresponding to the community.